# matplotlib: scatter plot from string

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data in this form in a text file:

```
strings  year  avg
--       --    --
abc      2012  1854
abc      2013  2037
abc      2014  1781
pqr      2011  1346
pqr      2012  1667
xyz      2015  1952
```

I want to make a scatter plot with (distinct) strings on the x-axis, (distinct) year on the y-axis and the size of marker (circle) should be equal to the avg. I am having trouble implementing it in matplotlib, because the scatter function expects a numerical value for x,y (data positions). Because of that, I am unable to assign strings as x and year as y. Do I need to pre-process this data further?

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you have?

Comment: @DavidG it's 2.0.2

Comment: Matplotlib 2.1 _does_ support categorical data plotting. Therefore, if upgrading your version is an option, then that should solve your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Plotting categorical variable scatter with matplotlib >=2.1

In matplotlib 2.1 you may just supply the strings to the scatter function.

```
strings = ["abc","abc","abc","pqr","pqr","xyz"]
year = list(range(2012,2018))
avg = [1854, 2037,1781,1346,1667,1952]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.scatter(strings, year, s=avg)

plt.show()
```

#### Plotting categorical variable scatter with matplotlib < 2.1

In matplotlib below 2.1 you need to plot the data against some index which corresponds to the categories. Then set the labels accordingly.

```
strings = ["abc","abc","abc","pqr","pqr","xyz"]
year = list(range(2012,2018))
avg = [1854, 2037,1781,1346,1667,1952]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

u, ind = np.unique(strings, return_inverse=True)
plt.scatter(ind, year, s=avg)
plt.xticks(range(len(u)), u)

plt.show()
```

Output in both cases

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed answer! :)

Comment: Your first code snipped isn't working on matplotlib 2.1. Can you figure out what's wrong there?

Comment: @SaadH The code is working fine on matplotlib 2.1, that is why I put it in the answer. If you have a problem running it, you may first check your matplotlib version `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.__version__)` and then provide a clear problem description: What is the output, is there an error etc.?

Comment: Okay, the problem was not with the version but the 2nd line: 
year = range(2012,2018)
changing it to: year = [2012,2013,2014,2011,2012,2015]
resolves the issue

Answer (score 1):

Even I wanted the same and found an easier way. You can use Seaborn, which is a library based on Matplotlib.

You can give the text on either axis and time/year on the other axis. To get maximum Visualization you can set the limit for both the axis. Lets give 'df' as the name to your dataframe

```
import seaborn as sns

minYear = df['year'].min()
maxYear = df['year'].max()
pl = sns.catplot(x = strings,y = year, data = df)
pl.set(ylim=(minYear,maxYear))
```

This will give you the best possible visualization.